# Monitor manual cluster with ray

Tags: python, ray

I don't seem to find in the [documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/). 
Let's say I create my cluster with `ray start --head` as stated in the documentation. How can I monitor the cluster? When I write the standard command `ray monitor`, it always throws me an error because I haven't included any `CLUSTER_CONFIG_FILE`.

I can even add another computer to the cluster with the command `ray start --address='<ip-and-port>'` but I'm not able to monitor anything that is happening, if I have dashboard activated I can see the cluster in the web interface, but otherwise, I can with the command line. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the monitor command requires an autoscaler setup. Please take a look at https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoscaling.html

Also, `ray monitor` doesn't seem to be officially supported because I couldn't find the command from the official document's package references. https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package-ref.html